# Sequential model prediction

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I take data from file:

```
y = np.genfromtxt('dataY.txt', dtype=np.float32) #input data for target dataset
x = np.genfromtxt('dataX.txt', dtype=np.float32)#input data for input dataset
```

I split the data accordingly

```
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split (x,y,test_size=.2)
train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xtrain, ytrain))
valid_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xtest, ytest))
```

The `dataY.txt` file is made by 65 rows. Each row includes 100 numbers that I want the NN to guess after the training, given the input X.

The `dataX.txt` file is made by 65 rows, one for each Y. Each row includes 100 numbers. So given a hundred numbers I want to guess 100 new numbers.

I define and train the NN:

```
N = 100
M = 100

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(N,1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(N, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(N, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(N, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(M))

model.compile( loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
model.fit(train_data, epochs=4, validation_data=valid_data)
```

PROBLEM 1: before training

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 100, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (100, 1, 1).
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 100, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (100, 1, 1).
2021-07-12 17:46:16.136364: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
```

and after the training is complete:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 100, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 100, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 1, 1).
(100, 1, 100)
```

Is this fatal? How do I fix this?

PROBLEM 2:

```
X_final_test = np.genfromtxt('testX.txt', dtype=np.float32)# test input
```

takes data from a file with one single row and 100 numbers. Its shape is `(100,)` BUT

```
pred = model.predict (X_final_test)
```

has a `(100,1,100)` shape, so I don't know what to plot to confront it with my known result. What is the problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: I'm guessing you want your sequential model to have 100 inputs, not 1. Is it true that you have 100 inputs mapped 100 outputs?

Comment: The inputs must be 100 numbers, the output 100 numbers. Something is wrong and I don't know why. y's shape is (65, 100), the same for x.

Answer (score 1):

Change your model definition to reflect that you have 100 inputs:

```
N_in = 100
N_hid = 100 #good practice to separate these
N_out = 100

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, N_in)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(N_hid, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(N_hid, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(N_hid, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(N_out))

model.compile( loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
model.fit(train_data, epochs=4, validation_data=valid_data)
```

What you're doing now is you're specifying that it has 1 input and it's expanding to that. To ensure that your data is the right shape, make sure that it is of size [B, 100], where B is the batch size for your processing (which can be 1 when debugging).